# Laravel how save a model to the database as a new one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, observers

Because of unit testing our classes looks like this:

```
class MyObserverClass
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model= $model;
    }

    public function saved(OtherModel $otherModel)
    {
        //Some condition
        while(...) {
                //$this->model->exists = false;
                $this->model->property = "x-value";
                $this->model->sub_id   = $otherModel->id;
                //Other props...
                $this->model->state = model::STATE;
                $this->model->save();
        }
     }
```

But when I run this, the same model get overridden x times, and only the last one will be in the database.

How I can force laravel to save the model as a new one in the database? I was trying with the `exists` property but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `newInstance` method to create new object instance:

```
while(...) {
    $model = $this->model->newInstance();    
    $model->property = "x-value";
    $model->sub_id   = $otherModel->id;

    //Other props...
    $model->state = model::STATE;
    $model->save();
}
```

However if you create many same or similar object in this loop, you could use `replicate` method to create one base object and to change only some properties.

Comment: In this case when I use unit test will be the mocked model I passed overridden?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
while(...) {
 $model = new self;
 $model -> name = $name;
 ....
 $model -> save();
}
```

or you can pass an array to insert to create method

```
// Create a new user in the database...
$user = Model::create(['name' => 'John']);
```